# There is a problem with the file path when using the adb push soft link file

Tags: ubuntu, adb, symlink, wsl-2

I work in WSL2 ubuntu, and use windows adb tools as for WSL2 ubuntu adb tools cannot find adb device.
and windows adb tools work well in WSL2 ubuntu expect push some folders.At the same time, a soft connection is established for the adb tool of the window platform.

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/win11_abd_tools /usr/bin/adb
```

I want to push this folder to adb device

```
folder_a/
├── file_a
└── soft_file_a -> file_a
```

normally, use the command below to push to adb devices

```
adb push ./folder_a /path/to/adb_devices/
```

but got error

```
lzlang@PC-PF3LZ5FP:~$ adb push ./folder_a /data/local/tmp/
adb: error: cannot lstat './folder_a\soft_file_a': No such file or directory
./folder_a\: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped.
```

Is there any good way to solve my problem